# Edit Single Product Page for A Specific Product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to re-arrange the elements (price, wishlist button and others) on the single product page for only specific products. The reason is, the client i am working for sells Gift Vouchers and needs the arrangement for the Gift Vouchers single product page to be different from regular products. The gift vouchers are just about 4 so i don't mind doing this for each of them or if possible do it for the category they belong to.

I have looked online but the answers i find apply to all products rather than specific ones.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Based on the category you get for products, you can use 'if' condition for Gift vouchers.

Comment: You should provide some code in your answer, even if it applies to all products (remember that StackOverFlow is coding oriented)… Then we will be able to help you to target specific products (or product categories). Actually your question is just too vague, so a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to obviously create a template file for those 4 products, which is different from the default single-product template.

If you have done that you can use the following code to point them to that template file:

```
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
 global $post;

 if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
      $single_template = 'location_of_your_template_file';
 }
 return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
```

Now obviously the above code works for all products, you could for example change the if statement to manually check for certain post ID's:

```
$post_ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);
 if ($post->post_type == 'product' && in_array($post->ID, $post_ids) {
      $single_template = 'location_of_your_template_file';
 }
```

Or, better in my opinion check for a certain category:

```
if ($post->post_type == 'product' && has_category("category_name_here", $post->ID) {
      $single_template = 'location_of_your_template_file';
 }
```

Whichever you prefer, hope it helps.